# redux state is undefined in useEffect and useSelector

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am new to **redux**. Currently I am working on a project that shows nearby bike stations on map by API call. So that means most of the redux actions are async and returns some data for next api call in another action. When I dispatch all my actions in useEffect and taking **states** with useSelector it is showing them at first render and **returning undefined** after a refresh. *This is the common problem I will face while I work with redux, redux-thunk, useEffect, useSelector*.

*I have tried async function inside useEffect hook to wait for each action call to finish*

**Actions :**

```
export const fetchIPLocation = () => {
    return async (dispatch) => {
        try {
            let response = await fetch(`https://ip.nf/me.json`)
            if(response.ok) {
                let data = await response.json()
                dispatch({
                    type: FETCH_IP_LOCATION,
                    payload: data.ip.ip
                })
            }
        } catch (error) {
            
        }
    }
}

export const fetchUserData = (IPadress) => {
    return async (dispatch) => {
        try {
            let response = await fetch(`http://api.ipstack.com/${IPadress}?access_key=15633b167163620b5cd84ef60db62414`)
            if(response.ok) {
                let data = await response.json()
                dispatch({
                    type: FETCH_USER_DATA,
                    payload: data
                })
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
}
```

**Reducer :**

```
import { initialState } from "../store";
import { FETCH_IP_LOCATION, FETCH_USER_DATA, FETCH_NETWORKS } from "../action";

export const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_IP_LOCATION:
            return {
                ...state,
                ipLocation: action.payload,
                isLoading: false,
            }
        case FETCH_USER_DATA:
            return {
                ...state,
                userData: action.payload,
                isLoading: false,
            }
        case FETCH_NETWORKS: 
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoading: false,
                bikeNetworks: action.payload,
            }
    }
}
```

**MapComponent.jsx which renders leaflet map and uses all states**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import '../styles/MapComponent.css';
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from 'react-leaflet';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { fetchIPLocation, fetchUserData, getUserData } from '../redux/action/';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
 
const MapComponent = () => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const [latitude, setLatitude] = useState(0)
    const [longitude, setLongitude] = useState(0)
    const [checkCords, setCheckCords] = useState(false)

    const ipLocation = useSelector((state) => state.ipLocation)
    const userCountry = useSelector((state) => state.userData.country_code)
    
    console.log(userCountry)

 
    useEffect(() => {
      if(navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((position) => {
              setLatitude(position.coords.latitude)
              setLongitude(position.coords.longitude)
              setCheckCords(true)
          })
      }
    }, [])

    useEffect(async () => {
      await dispatch(fetchIPLocation())
      await dispatch(fetchUserData(ipLocation))
    }, [])

  return (
      !checkCords ? <h1>Loading...</h1> :
    <MapContainer center={[latitude, longitude]} zoom={11}>
      <TileLayer
        attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
      />
      <Marker position={[latitude, longitude]}>
        <Popup>
          A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
        </Popup>
      </Marker>
    </MapContainer>
  
  )
}

export default MapComponent
```

**redux store:**

```
import { createStore, compose, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import persistStore from 'redux-persist/es/persistStore';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';
import persistReducer from 'redux-persist/es/persistReducer';
import { rootReducer } from '../reducer';

export const initialState = {
    ipLocation: [],
    userData: [],
    bikeNetworks: [],
    bikeStations: [],
    isLoading: true,
}

const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    storage
}

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)

const configureStore = createStore(
    persistedReducer,
    initialState,
    composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk))
)

const persistor = persistStore(configureStore)

export { configureStore, persistor }
```

**app.js and Provider :**

```
import './App.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import MapComponent from './components/MapComponent'
import { configureStore, persistor } from './redux/store';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';
import { BrowserRouter,  Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import {Container, Row, Col} from 'react-bootstrap';


const App = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={configureStore}>
      <PersistGate persistor={persistor} loading={null}>
        <Container fluid={true} className='px-0 overflow-hidden'>
          <BrowserRouter>
           <Row>
             <Col md={12}>
               <Routes>
                 <Route exact path='/' element={<MapComponent />} />
               </Routes>
             </Col>
           </Row>
          </BrowserRouter>
        </Container>
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: can you share the code for creating the store and wrapping the app using Provider?

Comment: Edited Provider and redux store

Comment: set a default :  case in your reducer. Same problem  happend with me long ago. It may help

Comment: thanks you very much @WasifAli . I forgot to set a default case for switch statement. now it is working

Comment: @Saidamir glad to hear :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **MapComponent.jsx** `ipLocation` from the useSelector wouldnt update after the first function (ie. `fetchIPLocation()`) and before the second function (ie. `fetchUserData()`).

What you have to do is to dispatch the action `fetchUserData(ipLocation)`  after getting the response from the action `fetchIPLocation` in **Actions** file.

```
// Action
export const fetchIPLocation = () => {
    return async (dispatch) => {
        try {
            let response = await fetch(`https://ip.nf/me.json`)
            if(response.ok) {
                let data = await response.json()
                dispatch({
                    type: FETCH_IP_LOCATION,
                    payload: data.ip.ip
                })
                dispatch(fetchUserData(data.ip.ip)
            }
        } catch (error) {
            
        }
    }
}
```

and in useEffect of **MapComponent.jsx** just call `dispatch(fetchIPLocation())`

Comment: in this is way, it is working and logging userData obj itself on console, but if I try to access the props of userData obj like const countryCode = useSelector((state) => state.userData.country_code) , it is returning state.userData is unidefined